# Self Signed Certificate: Can I trust the client being indeed the owner of the public key?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am playing around with OpenSSL, and in my server code I have the following:

```
rc = SSL_get_verify_result(ssl);
printf("SSL_get_verify_result(): %i\n", rc);

cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl);
printf("SSL_get_peer_certificate(): %p\n", cert);

pkey = X509_get_pubkey(cert);
printf("X509_get_pubkey(): %p\n", pkey);
```

`SSL_get_verify_result()` returns `X509_V_ERR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN` which is expected.

My question is, can I trust that the client is actually the owner of the pub key that I get using `X509_get_pubkey()` after `SSL_get_verify_result()` has failed with the above error.

In other words, can I perform authentication using this public key (assuming my server somehow has knowledge of this public key).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trust that the peer owns the private key of the certificate he supplies, because he also supplies a digital signature which is checked by SSL using the public key in the certificate. Only the owner of the private key can do that.

Whether you trust that the peer owns the identity expressed in the subject DN comes down to whether you trust the issuer, which in the case of a self-signed certificate is himself.

And whether that identity is *authorised* to communicate with your application is yet another question, which only your application can answer.

Comment: "You can trust that the peer owns the private key of the certificate he supplies". Thanks! That was what I was looking for.